# Using single full text index instance of Hibernate in multiple applications

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate Search in spring boot application and I created indexes. But in my case there are many applications and I'm using single data base , single entities in multiple modules. When I update entity in one application , It creates indexes but these indexes will create for this application and when I update that entity , new indexes will be created but I already have created indexes for this entity. Eventually I get multiple indexes for single entity. I used different index location for every application. I tried to use same location but in this case I got errors. How I can use single index for all application. I want to say shortly I must to do same all indexes. Multiple applications must to use single index.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much in uncharted territory here; we frequently see people with multiple instances of the same application, but rarely (if ever) multiple different applications.

You might be able to share the indexes using a [JMS](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-architecture-jms) or [JGroups](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-architecture-jgroups) master/slave architecture, but if all of your applications run on the same machine, it's clearly overkill. Also, setup will be rather complex.

A perhaps better solution would be for you to use the experimental [Elasticsearch integration](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-integration).

You will have to make sure to use the `validate` [index management strategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-schema-management-strategy), and initialize your production Elasticsearch cluster from a dump created in a development environment with the `create` strategy. Then everything should work fine, you'll be able to send updates and search queries concurrently from multiple applications.

Note that, if you ever change your index mapping, you should make sure to update the schema of your Elasticsearch cluster, either manually (but it might be tricky) or by reinitializing the cluster from a dump created in a development environment.

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks a lot. I used single indexes. where occur any change I listen and send it to BuildSearchIndex service via JMS or RestTemplate of Spring  and It does indexing